# Command not found - Oh-My-Zsh

Tags: macos, maven, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I recently installed zsh and oh-my-zsh in my Mac. Now when I try to run a maven command from the terminal, I am getting the following error.

```
$ mvn install
zsh: command not found: mvn
```

I have installed Apache maven in /Applications directory. Currently my .zshrc file looks like below.

```
plugins=(git brew pip mvn mysql-macports python sublime tmux osx)

# ####################
# Maven Config Options
# ####################
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.3.3
export PATH=$PATH:M2_HOME/bin
```

As seen above, I appended location of maven installation to the path. But I am still getting errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin`. Notice the `$` I added. Also, no need to export; export sets a flag in bash/zsh/etc., and it only needs to be set once.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

## Question:

`➜  ~ mvn`

`zsh: command not found: mvn`

## Answer:

###### step 1:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

###### step 2:(Add at the end of the file)

```
source ~/.bash_profile;
```

###### step 3:(Execution shell)

```
> source ~/.bash_profile
```

#### You can use mvn :

```
➜  / mvn

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
.......
```

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? Sourcing `bash_profile` in `.zshrc` is a short term fix and may cause problems later. `Bash` and `zsh` are completely different shells with their own set of configuration files. See the [zsh intro page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html) for more info.

Comment: Now you will get the .zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh file which includes all of your previous exports before oh-my-zsh installed will save in that file. So you can grab them from there and include in your newly overwritten .zhrc file will enable the commands back for you. Enjoy!

Comment: @compuphys what answer would you suggest then? I'm curious. From what I can see once bash_profile is sourced in .zshrc, all the paths available now in zshrc and in the future the user will only be using zsh to install any tools they want to. I'm not sure if I see an issue here nor do I see you long term solution.

Comment: Thanks. It worked but I was a little bit confused by the format you used for the steps, I think it would be a better idea not to mark steps as code because it Is confusing.

Comment: add what? this is a partial answer.

Comment: @compuphys Some software, e.g. Homebrew, e.g.2. PhantomJS, give instructions for setting the path by adding an "export PATH" command (or similar) to your .bash_profile/.zprofile (depending on macos version). Thus this answer lets the user follow such instructions without having to mess about deciding if it belongs somewhere else or not.

Comment: Note that Apple changed the default shell to `zsh` since Catalina, thus the profile file changed from `.bash_profile` to `.zprofile`.

Answer (score 61):

Just add:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to .zshrc

Comment: You saved my life. thanks it work with source ~/.profile

Comment: This works but sourcing `bash_profile` in `.zshrc` is a short term fix and may cause problems later. `Bash` and `zsh` are completely different shells with their own set of configuration files. See the [zsh intro page](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html) for more info.

Comment: doesn't fix anything actually, no library still, and no bash_profile

Answer (score 31):

I had a similar problem after installing oh-my-zsh, but for adb command.
Looks like the `PATH` is shortened when oh-my-zsh is installed. I solved it using following steps.

1. Open the `.zshrc` file

   ```
   sudo nano ~/.zshrc
   ```
2. Look for `# User configuration`

   Un-comment the following line:

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH"
   ```
3. Save the file.
4. `source ~/.zshrc`

Give this one a try for other similar command not found errors.

Answer (score 20):

Try below steps:

Open terminal and run command `vi ~/.zshrc`

Add below lines in file:

```
export M2_HOME=/Users/<username>/Downloads/apache-maven-3.6.3 
export PATH=${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
export PATH
```

Save file successfully

Open another terminal instance & run command `mvn -version`

It should work!

Answer (score 10):

I think the answers above are too deep. It could be that the person does not have Maven installed on their Local PC. So please run the command below on your terminal

`brew install maven`

Afterwards on your IntelliJ or the terminal where the project is located run the command

`mvn clean install`

Use the command to double check if it was installed
`mvn --version`

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: open zshrc file

```
sudo nano ~/.zshrc
```

step 2: add **'mvn'** in plugins section

```
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions mvn)
```

step 3: add maven configuration in zshrc file. (**make sure your apache maven extract directory. I have extracted in /opt folder**)

```
# Maven Config Options
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.4
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

step 4: save the chnages

```
ctrl+o
ENTER
ctrl+z
```

Step 5: reload zshrc file

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Step 6: go to terminal and verify

```
mvn -v
```

Output :

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4
 Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.8.4
 Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11- 
 openjdk-amd64 Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: 
 "linux", version: "5.4.0-89-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: Thankyou. I had installed and moved to /opt correctly. But this additional config was remaining. It perfectly worked. I'm using mac m1, maven 3.8.6

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by **@4ae1e1** in his comment, `$` have to be added before `M2_HOME` while referring it in the `PATH` variable, as follows:

```
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.3.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin/
```

Once added, as others suggested, source the `~/.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

- First, as 4ae1e1 pointed out, you missed the `$` in `PATH=$PATH:M2_HOME/bin`
- Second, don't forget to run `source ~/.zshrc` to take the settings into effect instantly.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a mac you can use Homebrew to install maven and all it's paths
Use:

```
brew install maven
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the exact same issue, this is what worked for me:

1. `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
2. add this:

   ```
   export PATH=your maven path/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
   ```
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, select "Y", Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. `source ~/.zshrc`
5. Validate: `mvn -version`

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, you can add the following to your .zshrc file.

If you have not, download maven from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

```
# Maven
export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.8.3/bin:${PATH} # you could have it in a different directory
```

To edit .zshrc, you can use an existing text editor such as vim.

```
$ cd ~
$ vim .zshrc
```

Use `i` to insert the export statements. Once inserted, use `esc`to exit insert mode. Then use `:wq!` to save and quit the editor. Finally, source the file to see the effects of your new changes.

```
$ source .zshrc
```

Now try `mvn` and you should see something like this.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.049 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-11T13:34:20-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vi ~/.zshrc
```

add `source ~/.bash_profile` to ~/.zshrc file, after the  line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

open up a new terminal tab and execute `mvn`, and it will start working.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. So created .zshrc file and added below in that file.
export M2_HOME=/Users/gandharavmehra/Desktop/Development/Tools/apache-maven-3.6.3
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin

after this
gandharvmehra@MacBook-Pro ~ % source ~/.zshrc

close the Terminal and open again

gandharamehra@MacBook-Pro ~ % mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)

it should work 100 percent

Answer (score 1):

First of all Download **Maven** from here https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

and extract it and go and open your **zshrc** with **nano**:

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

and paste these lines inside the file:

```
export M2_HOME="/Users/sanaebadi/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.7"
PATH="${M2_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

**

> you have to make sure that you put your correct USER name instead of
> my userName (sanaebadi)

**

> and you have to make sure from the version and directory of your maven
> that you already downloaded.

**

**

and relaunch the file after it : `source ~./zshrc`

and run this command to make sure you installed the maven on your system:

```
 mvn -version
```

you must to see some lines start with :

```
Apache Maven 3.8.7 (b89d5959fcde851dcb1c8946a785a163f14e1e29)
Maven home: /Users/sanaebadi/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.7 ...
.....
...
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

Combining other answers I got adb working on mac and zsh appending these two path lines to .zshrc:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# this are for Android Studio adb:
export PATH=~/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `.bash_profile` is for `/bin/bash` shell, for your `/bin/zsh` shell, the file is called `.zprofile`, you should do the same thing in `.zprofile` as in `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue today with mvn command not found

In my example problem was with incorrect path - I missed one / at the beginning of the path

1. .zshrc before change:
   export MAVEN_HOME=home/user/Tools/apache-maven-3.6.3
   export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
2. good to verify if maven path exists. In my case it was error using command below
   ls $MAVEN_HOME
3. .zshrc after fix one line
   export MAVEN_HOME=/home/user/Tools/apache-maven-3.6.3
   export PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
4. reload .zhsrc
   source .zshrc
5. mvn command found

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Catalina you will face this problem often.

1. Open your terminal
2. Just copy all your Path variables and create a .zshrc file (touch .zshrc)
3. open it (open ~/.zshrc) and paste them there,
4. save and refresh your .zsrhc file ( source ~/.zshrc).

I found this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfCbtMN9-Jo) very helpful to solve related problems.

Answer (score 0):

Install Maven on Mac OS. Download the latest version from the [Apache Maven site](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and select the Maven binary tar.gz file, for example, apache-maven-3.8.4-bin.tar.gz.

Then we extract the archive to our desired location.

**Adding Maven to the Environment Path**

First, let's open the terminal and switch to the directory where the files were extracted to and then log in as superuser or use below commands with sudo.

Second, we need to remove the tar.gz archive:

> rm Downloads/apache-maven*bin.tar.gz

Third, we have to fix the permissions and switch the Maven contents:

> chown -R root:wheel Downloads/apache-maven*
>
> mv Downloads/apache-maven* /opt/apache-maven

Then, let's archive the Admin session and add Maven binaries to the path and append:

> exit
>
> nano $HOME/.profile
>
> export PATH=$PATH:/opt/apache-maven/bin

Finally, we use Ctrl+x to save and exit from nano.

To load the new setup, let's run:

bash
Now, we test if Maven is installed successfully using the command below:

> mvn -version

We are now ready to use Maven on our Mac OS.

Reference : [How to Install Maven on Windows, Linux, and Mac](https://www.baeldung.com/install-maven-on-windows-linux-mac)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure intelliJ terminal with a custom Terminal or if you want fix "command not found",
follow these steps:

1. Click > File
2. Click > Settings
3. Click > Tools
4. Click > Terminal
5. Edit "Shell path" @ "Application Settings", change current path with:
   C:\Users\Work\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe --login

// The path you may have differs based on your OS, in example: "installationPath\Terminal Folder\bin\sh.exe --login"

6. Click > Apply
7. Click > Ok

I used git bash but technically it should work with every terminal. Do not forget to add --login after the *.exe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a syntax error:

The wrong usage was like this:

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Webstorm.app"
```

I updated:

```bash
export PATH="/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/Webstorm.app:$PATH"
```

and now it works

Answer (score -2):

step 1:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

step 2:(Add at the end of the file)

```
source ~/.bash_profile;
```

step 3 : (Save changes in Vim)

```
 :wq!
```

step 4:(Execution shell)

```
> source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score -2):

Best solution work for me

Open Finder-> go to folder /Users/ /usr/local/bin

open .zshrc with TextEdit

**.zshrc is hidden file so unhide it by command+shift+. press**

delete file content and type

**export PATH=~/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH**

**and save**

now

zsh: command not found Gone