# "zsh: command not found: mvn" intellij ver 2020.2 community on Mac system

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, maven-3

I am using **IntelliJ 2020.2.4 version on mac Catalina having JDK 1.8_127**. I also installed(unzipped) maven in a folder on my PC. I can get return of the version as ***maven 3.6.3*** when I query `mvn -version` from mac terminal. This is the good part.

Now went in to the IntelliJ terminal and queried `mvn -version`, I get `zsh: command not found: mvn`. BTW, while typing the mvn -version command, the command is highlighted in yellow, plus a green text popup in the bottom of the terminal.

I configured in the preferences under Maven, Maven home directory as (tried) both the bundled Maven (3) and the maven I unzipped in some folder on my mac. Both did not work.

Another weird thing

-(I) is when ever I restart the IDE (only then), I see maven tab on the right hand side vertical edge by clicking which we normally run maven life cycle commands like clean, install, verify etc., Once I click on it, it simply vanishes, until I restart the IDE.

-(II)When I try `maven -version` can return the correct version of maven as 3.6.3 from the unzipped installation. But when I open another mac terminal, the same command returns the message in the title above. What gives ?

Is this some thing permissions issue on Mac ?

How can I either
(1) use the unzipped maven binary on my mac which is version 3.6.3 inside IntelliJ (OR)
(2) use the bundled maven with IntelliJ by default.
(a) When I go to the location of this bundled maven location like `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin` and invoke `mvn -version` I get the same result as above.

I get to ask the following:

- (a) Why the bundled Maven is not working either inside IntelliJ or
  directly invoked from terminal

-(b) Why the external zipped install of
Maven could not be utilized inside the IntelliJ

Comment: Seems you do not have maven binary in your shell path. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935281/command-not-found-oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this in an Mac OS specific problem. This is what solved it for me:

Open a terminal and make the following:

```
> vim ~/.zshrc

a
export M2_HOME=/Applications/apache-maven-3.x.x
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_Home/bin/
ESC
:wq

> mvn -version
```

Where "/Applications/apache-maven-3.x.x" is the path and version of your [downloaded und unzipped maven](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) binary of course.

Hope this solves it for other Mac users as well.